# Trigger error "ORA-01403: no data found" when It is not fire

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating a trigger below, as long as I insert something already existed in the table, then print other wise do nothing.

```
create or replace trigger TR_insert
Before INSERT On A
For each row 

DECLARE
l_act integer;
l_name varchar(30);
l_minute integer;

Begin 

select count(1) into l_act
From A
Where Activity=:new.Activity;


if(l_act>0) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('There is duplicate.');
else
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
end if;

end;
```

It is working fine when I insert something existed, but when I insert new item, then it gives out error "SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found", why is that please?

Comment: Why would you create a trigger rather than creating a unique constraint?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just want to learn to use trigger.

Comment: But this isn't a useful thing for a trigger to do.  In general, a row-level trigger on `A` cannot query `A`-- that will generally cause a mutating table exception.  Triggers should not be used to validate conditions that require querying other rows in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because your select does not return any value for your new item. The below shud work.

```
begin

select count(1) into l_act
From A
Where Activity=:new.Activity;

if(l_act>0) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('There is duplicate.');
end if;

exception
when NO_DATA_FOUND then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');

end;
```

Comment: `if(l_act>0) then...` is pointless: if the code gets to that line, then there must be at least one row.